# kiosk mode: lightm toggles between DisplayServer x-0 and x-1

Tags: kiosk, lxsession, lightdm

I am running a Raspberry Pi 3B with a 7" touch display in kiosk mode. I am setting up Firefox to start on a specified web page, and have to specify the X server display number.  User pi is set to auto-login, and launch Firefox by adding this line:

> @firefox https:/10.1.1.224/admin/users/auto_pad --display=:0

to the file  `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`.

When everything runs right, this is what the `lightdm.log` file shows:

> DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log

I have about 20 of these devices in the field, and occasionally one of them changes to X-window display 1 after a reboot.  This is what the `lightdm.log` file shows:

> DisplayServer x-1: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-1.log

... but because Firefox is told to launch on display 0, the display just stays blank.  And further reboots will launch display 1 every time...

until I change the line in the `autostart` file to:

> @firefox https:/10.1.1.224/admin/users/auto_pad --display=:1

On the next reboot (or even just `service lightdm restart`), the displayserver switches back to display 0, but now Firefox is set to start on display 1, so the display is blank again...

Questions:

**What makes the display server start on display 1 instead of display 0?

Why does it always toggle back to display 0 after I ask Firefox to start on display 1?

How can I force the display server to always start on display 0?**